# converting svg graphic into image causing problems

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, svg, html2canvas

I need to convert [amChart](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) into an image using canvas. By using the following code:

```
$(function() { 
$("#btnSave").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#widget"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            // Convert and download as image 
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
            $("#img-out").append(canvas);
            // Clean up 
            //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
    });
});
```

});

But there is problem in the generated image, see the following svg chart in html page
[image]

while the generated image:

[image]

Comment: Without seeing teh svg markup, it's quite hard to know what happens there. But looking at [amChart's example](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-column-chart/), they seem to absolutely position their svg, which could be the reason for deduplication (in case you called it twice). Also, they do use clipPath, elements, I don't know how good html2canvas is with that. You may want to try a library especially made for svg before calling html2canvas. https://jsfiddle.net/co5646r4/

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido
Now I can convert it :)